# Joining two files with regular expression in Unix (ideally with perl)

Tags: linux, perl, awk, expression

I have following two files disconnect.txt and answered.txt:

disconnect.txt

```
2011-07-08 00:59:06,363 [socketProcessor] DEBUG ProbeEventDetectorIS41Impl:459 - AnalyzedInfo had ActCode = Disconnected from: 40397400012 to:40397400032
2011-07-08 00:59:06,363 [socketProcessor] DEBUG ProbeEventDetectorIS41Impl:459 - AnalyzedInfo had ActCode = Disconnected from: 4035350012 to:40677400032
```

answered.txt

```
2011-07-08 00:59:40,706 [socketProcessor] DEBUG ProbeEventDetectorIS41Impl:404 - Normal Call Answered, billingid=2301986 from: 40397643433 to:403###34**
2011-07-08 00:59:40,706 [socketProcessor] DEBUG ProbeEventDetectorIS41Impl:404 - Normal Call Answered, billingid=2301986 from: 3455334459 to:1222
2011-07-08 00:59:48,893 [socketProcessor] DEBUG ProbeEventDetectorIS41Impl:404 - Normal Call Answered, billingid=2220158 from: 4035350012 to:40677400032
```

I would like to create a join on these files based on the from: and to: fields and the output should be matching field from answered.txt. For example, in the above two files, the output would be:

```
2011-07-08 00:59:48,893 [socketProcessor] DEBUG ProbeEventDetectorIS41Impl:404 - Normal Call Answered, billingid=2220158 from: 4035350012 to:40677400032
```

I'm currently doing it by comparing each line in file 1 with each line in file 2, but want to know if an efficient way exists (these files will be in tens of gigabytes).

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have hundreds of millions of lines?

Unless the files are sorted in such a way that you can expect the order of the from: and to: to at least vaguely correlate, this is a job for a database.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are large the quadratic algorithm will take a lifetime.

Here is a Ruby script that uses just a single hash table lookup per line in answered.txt:

```
def key s
  s.split('from:')[1].split('to:').map(&:strip).join('.')
end

h = {}
open 'disconnect.txt', 'r' do |f|
  while s = f.gets
    h[key(s)] = true
  end
end

open 'answered.txt', 'r' do |f|
  while a = f.gets
    puts a if h[key(a)]
  end
end
```

Like [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) says, it all depends on the number of lines in disconnect.txt. If that's a really big<sup>1</sup> number, then you will probably not be able to fit all the keys in memory and you will need a database.

---

<sup>1. The number of lines in disconnect.txt multiplied by (roughly) 64 should be less than the amount of memory in your machine.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

First, sort the files on the from/to timestamps if they are not already sorted that way.  (Yes, I know the from/to appear to be stored as epoch seconds, but that's still a timestamp.)

Then take the sorted files and compare the first lines of each.

- If the timestamps are the same, you have a match.  Hooray!  Advance a line in one or both files (depending on your rules for duplicate timestamps in each) and compare again.
- If not, grab the next line in whichever file has the earlier timestamp and compare again.

This is the fastest way to compare two (or more) sorted files and it guarantees that no line will be read from disk more than once.

If your files aren't appropriately sorted, then the initial sorting operation may be somewhat expensive on files in the "tens of gigabytes each" size range, but:

1. You can split the files into arbitrarily-sized chunks (ideally small enough for each chunk to fit into memory), sort each chunk independently, and then generalize the above algorithm from two files to as many as are necessary.
2. Even if you don't do that and you deal with the disk thrashing involved with sorting files larger than the available memory, sorting and then doing a single pass over each file will still be a *lot* faster than any solution involving a cartesian join.

Or you could just use a database as mentioned in previous answers.  The above method will be more efficient in most, if not all, cases, but a database-based solution would be easier to write and would also provide a lot of flexibility for analyzing your data in other ways without needing to do a complete scan through each file every time you need to access anything in it.